# Error in executing ubuntu sys commands from python3 code

Tags: shell, command-line, ubuntu-16.04, python-3.6

I want to execute the following commands:

```
import subprocess
import os

JAVA_HOME = "export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64/"
HADOOP_HOME = "export HADOOP_HOME=/opt/hadoop-2.7.3"

os.system(JAVA_HOME)
os.system(HADOOP_HOME)
#proc1 = subprocess.run([self.JAVA_HOME])
#proc2 = subprocess.run([self.HADOOP_HOME])
```

As you can see I have tried both the ways using subprocess and os.system(), but nothing seems to work! I keep getting the error each time:

```
Cannot find hadoop installation: $HADOOP_HOME or $HADOOP_PREFIX must be set or hadoop must be in the path
```

What can I be possible doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Adding code for a clear picture:

```
def execute(self):
    self.username = "jdbc:hive2:sample1"
    self.pswd = input("Enter password: ")
    self.database = input("Enter database name: ")
    self.table = input("Enter table name: ")
    self.sqlQuery = "select * from " + self.database + "." + self.table + ";"
    self.command = self.options + " -u \"" + self.username + "\" -p \"" + self.pswd + "\" -e \"" + self.sqlQuery + "\""

    os.environ['JAVA_HOME'] = "/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64/"
    os.environ['HADOOP_HOME'] = "/opt/hadoop-2.7.3"
    proc = subprocess.Popen(self.command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
```

I am calling this function from Main program to set the env variables and then run the command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't modify the environment of your *current* process by setting an environment variable in a *child* process (which is what you are trying to do).  When you use `os.system`, Python forks a new process and then uses your shell to run the specified commands.  When the shell script completes, the process exits. Any environment variables you set inside that shell process are gone as soon as it exits.

If you want to modify the current process environment so that it will be inherited by children, just set keys in the `os.environ` variable:

```
os.environ['JAVA_HOME'] = "/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64/"
os.environ['HADOOP_HOME'] = "/opt/hadoop-2.7.3"
```

Comment: So this command is to be set in this child process itself? So that it will set for the currect dev environment? Because I jus replaced the 'os.system("...") by 'os.environ['JAVA_HOME'] = "/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64/"
os.environ['HADOOP_HOME'] = "/opt/hadoop-2.7.3"' as mentioned, but that dnt hlp...

Comment: Without seeing more of your code there's really not much I can suggest.  What I have suggested here is how you set environment variables if you're going to be calling out to other programs from your Python code. Update your question to show code that accurately demonstrates the problem and we can provide you with better answers.